# Exterior points in topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{N}$ which consists of $\varnothing$ and all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ of the form $\{G:\,G ⊆\mathbb{N}\text{ and }\mathbb{N}\setminus\Bbb G\text{ is finite}\}$.   Then

> Find the exterior set of the set $A=\{2,4,6,8,...120\}$.

Sol: $\text{Ext}(A)=\{21,22,23,...\}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Please take a look at the formatting for future reference; your usage can be improved substantially.

Comment: The choice of $21$ seems rather arbitrary. And why is $22$ in the exterior of $A$, when it is clearly an element of $A$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli that is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $O\subset A$ is open, then $\mathbb N\setminus O$ is finite.  But $\mathbb N\setminus O\supset\mathbb N\setminus A\supset \{1,3,5,7,\dots \}$. Hence $\mathbb N\setminus O$ is infinite...  Thus the only open set in $A$ is $\emptyset$.

Thus the exterior of $A$ is the whole space $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain it more, i'm confused, i know we don't have the even numbers in $\mathbb{N\setminus A}$ so how \Int$\mathbb{N\setminus A}$ contain the even ones, i didn't understand ur answer very well , could u solve it for 2 or any even number

Comment: @user517932 for starters there are some typos:  $G$ should be $\mathbb N$...

Comment: @user517932 try reading it now...  the idea is that the interior is empty,  because for any open set $O\subset A$, $\mathbb N\setminus O\supset\mathbb N\setminus A$, and the latter set is infinite...  leaving us with no nontrivial open sets in $A$...

Comment: @user517932 well, since $A$ contains no nontrivial open sets,  the interior of $A$ is empty...  then, the complement of the empty set is $\mathbb N$...  I'm using the definition of exterior as "complement of interior"...